# Find necessary and sufficient conditions for ordinal monotonicity.

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, ordinals, monotone-functions

First of all let's we remember the following result.

> **Theorem**
>
> Let be $\lambda$ and ordinal: a predicate $\mathbf P$ is true for any $\alpha$ in $\lambda$ when the truth of $\mathbf P$ for any $\beta$ in $\alpha$ implies that for $\alpha$.

Let be now $f$ a function from an order $(X,\mathcal U)$ into an order $(Y,\mathcal V)$: we will say that $f$ is monotone if for any $a$ and $b$ in $X$ the inequality
$$
a\preccurlyeq_\mathcal U b
$$
implies the inequality
$$
f(a)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal V f(b)
$$
So let's we prove the following result.

> **Conjecture**
>
> A function $f$ from an ordinal $\lambda$ into an order $(X,\mathcal O)$ is monotone if and only if the following holds:
>
> > - for any $\delta$ in $\lambda$ the inequality
> >   \begin{equation}
> >               f(\delta)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal O f(\delta+1)
> >               \tag{1}
> >               \label{successive imagine}
> >           \end{equation}
> >   holds;
>
> > - if $\alpha$ in $\lambda$ is limit then the inequality
> >   \begin{equation}
> >               f(\beta)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal O f(\alpha)
> >               \tag{2}
> >               \label{limit imagine}
> >           \end{equation}
> >   holds for any $\beta$ in $\alpha$.
>
> *Proof* Let's we assume that ineq. \eqref{successive imagine}-\eqref{limit imagine} hold and thus let's we prove even the proposition
> \begin{equation}(\forall\alpha)\Biggl((\alpha\in\lambda)\to\biggl((\forall\beta)\Big((\beta\in\alpha)\to\big(f(\beta)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal O f(\alpha)\big)\Big)\biggl)\Biggl)
>     \tag{3}
>     \label{monotonia}
>     \end{equation}
> holds.
> So let be $\alpha$ an element of $\lambda$ and thus let's we assume the proposition
> \begin{equation}
>         (\forall\gamma)\Big((\gamma\in\beta)\to\big(f(\gamma)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal O f(\beta)\big)\Big)
>         \tag{4}
>         \label{ipotesi induttiva}
>     \end{equation}
> for all $\beta$ in $\alpha$. Well if there exist an ordinal $\delta$ such that
> $$
>     \alpha=\delta+1
>     $$
> then any for any $\beta$ in $\alpha$ the inequality
> $$
>     \beta\le\delta
>     $$
> holds so that by inductive hypothesis and ineq. \eqref{successive imagine} the inequality
> $$
>     f(\beta)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal O f(\delta)\preccurlyeq_\mathcal O f(\delta+1)=f(\alpha)
>     $$
> holds; after all if $\alpha$ is limit then by ineq. \eqref{limit imagine} surely \ref{ipotesi induttiva} holds for $\alpha$ too: so we conclude \ref{ipotesi induttiva} holds for $\alpha$ always and thus by transfinite induction it generally holds for all $\alpha$ in $\lambda$ so that \ref{monotonia} holds.
>
> Conversely if $f$ is monotone then ineq. \eqref{successive imagine}-\eqref{limit imagine} trivially holds -by monotonicity definition.

So I ask if the conjecture is actually true and thus if I well proved it: could someone help me, please?